# ValidationMessages.properties not resolving with BindException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I'm probably just not doing this right, but here goes.

I have a Spring Boot application which I've added Hibernate Validator to and I have a command object that looks something like this:

```
public class SignupCommand {

  @Pattern(regexp = "^2[0-9]{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$")
  private String someDate;

  // getters/setters omitted for brevity

}
```

And a `@RequestMapping` in a controller that looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public AuthToken signUp(@Valid @RequestBody SignupCommand signupCommand,
                        BindingResult bindingResult) throws BindException {
  if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    throw new BindException(bindingResult);
  }
  return accountService.signUp(signupCommand);
}
```

This returns the JSON that I expect, with error codes and such that looks like this:

```
{
  "timestamp" : 1440256315621,
  "status" : 400,
  "error" : "Bad Request",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.validation.BindException",
  "errors" : [ {
    "codes" : [ "Pattern.signupCommand.someDate", "Pattern.someDate", "Pattern.java.lang.String", "Pattern" ],
    "arguments" : [ {
      "codes" : [ "signupCommand.someDate", "someDate" ],
      "arguments" : null,
      "defaultMessage" : "someDate",
      "code" : "someDate"
    }, [ ], "^2[0-9]{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$" ],
    "defaultMessage" : "must match \"^2[0-9]{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$\"",
    "objectName" : "signupCommand",
    "field" : "someDate",
    "rejectedValue" : "02-16-2015",
    "bindingFailure" : false,
    "code" : "Pattern"
  } ],
  "message" : "Validation failed for object='signupCommand'. Error count: 1",
  "path" : "/api/signup"
}
```

Here's where my problem occurs. I've tried putting the following in both `messages.properties` and `ValidationMessages.properties` at the root of the classpath (in `src/main/resources`) without any luck:

```
Pattern.signupCommand.someDate=Please enter a valid date in the format MM-DD-YYYY.
```

I guess I just don't have a good enough understanding of how Spring is doing the message resolution in conjunction with Hibernate Validator. Any help is appreciated!

### Update

I decided to add `message="{mymessage}"` to the `@Pattern` and put a `mymessage=Some message` in both files to see which one was being used. It looks like it is able to resolve messages when it's explicitly defined like that from the `ValidationMessages.properties` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using [this blog post](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/). Petri does it again!

I basically just needed to create an `@ExceptionHandler` and resolve the messages manually. I'm not sure why I thought throwing the `BindException` would automatically resolve my messages for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message=...` as your message key, the value will be used for all pattern validation error messages. It's unlikely this is what you want, as not all patterns will be for dates!

Going with the approach of `@Pattern(..., message="dateValidationMessage")` and using `dateValidationMesssage=...` as your message key will work.

Comment: This is the road I started down with hopes that I could use the "other" form of message resolution. Here's a link with more of what I'm talking about: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-framework-jsr-303-validation-and-custom-messages/. Namely, option 2 on that page. I'm wondering if my importing Hibernate Validator instead of just using Spring's JSR-303 support is what's causing my issues...